# Displaying All Data from Custom Post Type Fields through Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I have looked all over Google, trying to figure this out. I've made some progress but still stuck. I'm pretty new to ACF and custom post types. I have a custom post type of `Attorneys` that I setup through WCK. That post type has a field group with field names of `attorney_photo`, `attorney_name` and `attorney_areas_of_practice`. With the code below, I can get the `attorney_name` and `attorney_areas_of_practice` (repeater field) to display, but not the `attorney_photo`. I have the info displaying correctly on each attorneys specific page, but I need this page to be a listing of all the attorneys. Not sure what I am doing wrong with the image part.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'post_type' => 'attorneys'
);

query_posts($args);

if ( have_posts() ) : 

?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="attorney-preview">

<?php $photo = get_post_meta($post->ID,'attorney_photo', true); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $photo; ?>" />

<p><strong><a href=""><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'attorney_name', true); ?></a></strong></p>

<ul>
<?php
    while ( have_rows('attorney_areas_of_practice') ) : the_row();
        $attorney_area_of_practice = get_sub_field('attorney_area_of_practice');
        echo "<li>" . $attorney_area_of_practice . "</li>";
    endwhile;   
?>
</ul>

</div><!-- .attorney-preview -->

<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php endif; ?>

<?php
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the get_ID by $ post-> ID?
something like this    <?php $variable = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field_name', true); echo $variable;?>

Comment: I tried what you said @QuebrandoCabeca (I believe), but didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 1):

When you add image field through ACF plugin there are some options of return value. For example return value is: image object or return value is: image url, in your case return value might be selected as image object, not image url. That is why here with your code is being returned an array rather than only url.  To get only image url from this array, please write as following a bit change:

```
<?php $photo = get_post_meta($post->ID,'attorney_photo', true); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $photo['url']; ?>" />
```

Comment: That works on the page for one particular attorney, but isn't working on this page where I'm trying to display all of the attorneys.

Comment: BTW, I have it set to image object

Comment: Could you print_r($photo);  & reply back here what it give as output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 30,'order' => 'ASC','orderby' => 'title','post_type' => 'attorneys'));

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $attorney_photo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'attorney_photo', true);      
        $attorney_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'attorney_name', true); ?>

       <div class="attorney-preview">
         <img src="<?php echo $attorney_photo; ?>" />

          <p><strong><a href=""><?php echo $attorney_name; ?></a></strong></p>

       <ul>
       <?php
       while ( have_rows('attorney_areas_of_practice') ) : the_row();
       $attorney_area_of_practice = get_sub_field('attorney_area_of_practice');
       echo "<li>" . $attorney_area_of_practice . "</li>";
       endwhile;   
        ?>
     </ul>

    </div><!-- .attorney-preview -->

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php
     wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
     ?>
```